# Gerneral Transform InvalidOperation Exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, gis

I have ran into a problem that I am completely clueless about. I am receiving the following error message:

> The specified Visual and the Visual do not share a common ancestor, so there is no valid transformation between the two visuals.

This is being called when the user clicks on a point on the map. Any help would be appreciated. I have attached snippets of the error. If you need anymore code samples, just let me know.

Here is my relevant XAML:

(<)inf:DialogWindowBase x:Class="Alliance.CommonUI.Views.Maps.EsriMapView"

```
<Grid>
```

```
<Grid>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MyFeatureLayerInfoWindowTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="Content" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <esri:SimpleRenderer x:Key="MySimpleRenderer">
                    <esri:SimpleRenderer.Symbol>
                        <esri:SimpleFillSymbol Fill="#01FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#88000000" BorderThickness="2" />
                    </esri:SimpleRenderer.Symbol>
                </esri:SimpleRenderer>
 </Grid.Resources>

            <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Background="#FFE3E3E3" WrapAround="True" MouseClick="MyMap_MouseClick" MouseRightButtonDown="MyMap_MouseRightButtonDown" Extent="-9834972.92753924,4441899.425293319,-9833977.88119163, 4442762.485358352">
                <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer" Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" />
                <!--<esri:ArcGISLocalDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="Calvert_City" Path="C:\Users\jessical\Documents\ArcGIS\CalvertCity_Test.mpk"/>-->
                <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer  ID="Calvert_City" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer"/>
                <esri:FeatureLayer ID="MyFeatureLayer"  Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer/0"
                            Renderer="{StaticResource MySimpleRenderer}" />
</esri:Map>

            <Border Background="{StaticResource PanelGradient}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="20" Padding="5" BorderBrush="Black" >
                <esri:Legend Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}"
                         LayerIDs="Calvert_City"
                         LayerItemsMode="Tree"
                         ShowOnlyVisibleLayers="False"
                         Refreshed="Legend_Refreshed">
                    <esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" >
                                </CheckBox>
                                <Slider Maximum="1" Value="{Binding Layer.Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="50" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
                    <esri:Legend.LayerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" >
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </esri:Legend.LayerTemplate>
                </esri:Legend>
            </Border>
            <esri:InfoWindow x:Name="MyInfoWindow"
                         Padding="2"
                         CornerRadius="20"
                         Background="{StaticResource PanelGradient}"
                         Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}"
                         ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyFeatureLayerInfoWindowTemplate}"
                         MouseLeftButtonUp="MyInfoWindow_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using TransformToVisual. It should be TransformToAncestor.

Comment: I then recieve the error "The specified Visual is not an Ancestor."

Comment: Is this visual tree within the main window of the application?

Comment: Hmmnm. I actually think it may be in the DialogWindowBase.

Comment: Then you will have to change your code to transform to whatever window is the ancestor of that UIElement. Try using VisualTreeHelper to find the window containing the element, instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: OK. I am really new to this and I guess I just don't understand what I need to haha. All I have is EsriMapView.xaml and then the xmaml.cs of that. All of my code for the applcation is there.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me whether or not your UIElement is a visual child (sitting somewhere inside the Visual Tree) of the Main Window of the application. It doesn't seem to be the case, as it would not throw that exception if it were.

Comment: Even if it is, it is a much better approach not to tie your code to specific instances of UI Elements (such as referencing Application.Current.MainWindow), instead, use the VisualTreeHelper to find whatever window might be the container of your control.

Comment: Any advice for using the VisualTreeHelper? Thank-You for your help by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error using a third party control from SciChart.  I found that the error was being thrown under the covers and the debugger would make it look like the error was not being handled.  However, when I just turned off break on this type of exception and put a break point in my catch statement, the exception did not fall into my catch block.  I'm somewhat confused by all of this, but it seems to be working.

So my suggestion is to have the debugger not break on this type of exception and see how that works.

Comment: Hi Mike, Andrew from SciChart here :) I'm actually trying to fix this bug in scichart right now and landed on this page. We're using this code `GeneralTransform transform = element.TransformToVisual(otherElement);` and sometimes it throws. We try-catch and swallow the exception. If you, or anyone, knows a way to test if two visuals share a common ancestors, we can solve this!